# What is the best way to create or modify an index for fast searching in MySQL for unstructured information?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I am currently working on a project where I have to query data from different devices (example data attached below). Originally I was querying this data using

```
Select * From `table` Where `data` Like '%5.3%'
```

This took a long time for every query so I created a FULLTEXT index on data. I then wrote the following query to find the same product version, but it does not get all the same information the LIKE query gets.

```
Select `data` From `table` 
Where match(`data`)against('+"5.3"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I was wondering what the fastest way to search this type of data is. Should I modify the index I created or is there another method to do something like this. I have attached sample data where I try to find the version number **5.3** below. Thanks for your time

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_**5.3**p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.3
>   Key type: ssh-rsa
>   Key: AAAwtywtyhwhtgwJi40rvS84YLx5a19Psfdgr45ywrwsrH6msVLSwertwthgwmT
>   KnbqSuozljiCcdl/M/M/dyc+ivekkEsrKSPaPRLF46XeM
>   TfOZHfQKs7MYS1Zu4Ed/eB2hVPAUVQgsadfk9ReFr0QO985n+XJUQv55WZE8loZ4lQV+/G/5
>   Fingerprint: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: Full-text searching is optimized for finding words in text, not arbitrary substrings. There isn't really a way to index for what you're doing. If you know you'll need to look up the version frequently, you should process the data when you're inserting, and put that into a column of its own.

Comment: although in that particular instance, `like 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3%'` should perform better, as it can make use of an index on the field. obviously only useful if that is always the prefix